# JSON array elements as individual array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Say I have a JSON like the structure bellow

```
[{
    "name": "name1",
    "custitem_color": "3",
    "custitem_ribbon": "1",
    "baseprice": "10.00",
    "cost": "12.00"
}, {
    "name": "name2",
    "custitem_color": "4",
    "custitem_ribbon": "2",
    "baseprice": "20.00",
    "cost": "15.00"
}, {
    "name": "name3",
    "custitem_color": "6",
    "custitem_ribbon": "3",
    "baseprice": "30.00",
    "cost": "22.00"
}, {
    "name": "name4",
    "custitem_color": "8",
    "custitem_ribbon": "4",
    "baseprice": "40.00",
    "cost": "18.00"
}]
```

I want to generate the output as bellow

```
"name": ["name1","name2","name3"],  
"custitem_color":["3","4","6","8"]
```

I searched over SO but didn't get a match of this type. I'm curious to know if is there any library or workaround to get all the key's value as a separate array like the above I've mentioned. Any suggestions or point to any resource would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop through JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Comment: Although it arrived later, the answer by @Rory McCrossan is much easier to read and cleaner (better use of `var` *inside* the for loops). You may want to switch accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two loops. One to loop over each object within the array, and the other to loop over the properties of each individual object. From there you can build a new object containing the grouped values. Try this:

```
var output = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var item in data[i]) {
        output[item] ? output[item].push(data[i][item]) : output[item] = [data[i][item]];
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbq0e27w/)

This method has the benefit of being completely agnostic of the format of the input objects. If you add a new property, or the format is dynamic, the code will not need any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var result = {},
    len    = data.length, i, prop;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  for (prop in data[i]) {
    if (!result[prop]) {
      result[prop] = [];
    }

    result[prop].push(data[i][prop]);
  }
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/pihone/3/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/98753qL7/)

```
var a = [  {"name":"name1", "custitem_color":"3", "custitem_ribbon":"1", "baseprice":"10.00", "cost":"12.00"}, {"name":"name2", "custitem_color":"4", "custitem_ribbon":"2", "baseprice":"20.00", "cost":"15.00"}, {"name":"name3", "custitem_color":"6", "custitem_ribbon":"3", "baseprice":"30.00", "cost":"22.00"}, {"name":"name4", "custitem_color":"8", "custitem_ribbon":"4", "baseprice":"40.00", "cost":"18.00"} ]

var finalobj = {name : [],custitem_color : [],custitem_ribbon : [],baseprice : [],cost : []};
$.each(a,function(pos,val){
    finalobj.name.push(val.name);
    finalobj.custitem_color.push(val.custitem_color);
    finalobj.custitem_ribbon.push(val.custitem_ribbon);
    finalobj.baseprice.push(val.baseprice);
    finalobj.cost.push(val.cost);
})

console.log(finalobj);
```

Comment: You missed a trick there. The names are in the properties, so you did not need to hard-wire the array names. (and according to an SO comment, the values are dynamic so this will not work)

Answer (score 0):

```
var final_json = {"name":[],
           "custitem_color":[],
           "custitem_ribbon":[],
           "baseprice":[],
           "cost":[]
};

var init_json = [  {  
           "name":"name1",
           "custitem_color":"3",
           "custitem_ribbon":"1",
           "baseprice":"10.00",
           "cost":"12.00"
        },
        {  
           "name":"name2",
           "custitem_color":"4",
           "custitem_ribbon":"2",
           "baseprice":"20.00",
           "cost":"15.00"
        },
        {  
           "name":"name3",
           "custitem_color":"6",
           "custitem_ribbon":"3",
           "baseprice":"30.00",
           "cost":"22.00"
        },
        {  
           "name":"name4",
           "custitem_color":"8",
           "custitem_ribbon":"4",
           "baseprice":"40.00",
           "cost":"18.00"
        }
     ] ;


$.each(init_json ,function(pos,val){
    final_json.name.push(val.name);
    final_json.custitem_color.push(val.custitem_color);
    final_json.custitem_ribbon.push(val.custitem_ribbon);
    final_json.baseprice.push(val.baseprice);
    final_json.cost.push(val.cost);
})
```

Comment: You missed a trick there. The names are in the properties, so you did not need to hard-wire the array names. (and according to an SO comment, the values are dynamic so this will not work)